# CryptoPP cannot decode a cipher encrypted with Public key

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am using Cryptopp with Qt, My server sends a Public key to my client, the client encrypts a username with it and sends it (I have tested the cipher is sent properly) but server side i have an error : "invalid ciphertext", here is the code from my client :

```
QByteArray writtendata;
QDataStream streamBytes(&writtendata,QIODevice::WriteOnly);

streamBytes << quint16(0) << bytes;
streamBytes.device()->seek(0);
streamBytes << (quint16) (bytes.size() - sizeof(quint16));

int     written = socket->write(writtendata);
std :: cout << "sent : " << written << std :: endl ;
```

and server side :

```
        in >> datalenth;
        qDebug() << "datalength    : " << datalenth;

        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < datalenth)
            return;
        qDebug() << "byte available    : " << socket->bytesAvailable();
        QByteArray read;
        in >> read;
        qDebug() << "Read    : " << read.size();
        file.write(read);
        file.close();
        ifstream my;
        my.open("cipher.txt");

        string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(my)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        qDebug() << "str:  "<< str.size();
        cout << str <<endl ;
        string recovered = T->discryptor(str) ;
        std :: cout << "recovered : " << recovered << std :: endl;
        my.close();
```

I don't really know where the problem comes from.

Hope that anyone can shed some light on this.

Comment: What you really need is to debug your code (nobody can do that for you). Your question is too broad because it mixes crypto and I/O code and the error message suggests that your I/O code does not read the ciphertext properly. You should extract I/O code and debug it separately from crypto until you get the same and full data on the receiving end.

Comment: "please i need help..." - well, you did not provide the encryption or decryption code. Its hard to help without the relevant code. Effectively, all we can do is guess.